# Git rebase unpushed commits only

Tags: git

Is there a way to rebase which can only rewrite *local* history (not yet been pushed). I guess it would fallback to merge if that check is not passed.

Here's the problem boiled down to a simple feature-branch.

```sh
git checkout -b feature master
# DO WORK
git commit -m "COMMIT1"
git push -u origin feature # COMMIT1 is public
# DO WORK
git commit -m "COMMIT2"
git fetch origin master:master # background update master with some random commits
git rebase master # This rewrites both COMMIT1 and COMMIT2
git push # fails because COMMIT1 was rewritten
git push -f # banned by Infrastructure
```

So I'd like something like:

- `git rebase master` with something similar to `merge --ff-only` that fails if it would change public history
- `git pull --rebase` but with "rebase-or-merge" semantics

Comment: I assume you'd like something automatic, like git rebase --local, meaning you don't want to supply the actual list of commits to rebase

Comment: Correct, I want a "safe rebase" command I can alias/run without concern. I'm hoping something can cobbled together from the refs that does this.

Comment: rebase already does this. that's what it was built for.

Comment: In one sense, Git has no idea whether some other Git has your commits. But if you have your Git record things using *remote-tracking names* like `origin/somebranch`, that's your Git's memory of their (`origin`'s) `somebranch` as of the last time you and they synchronized, and usually that's good enough. If `origin/somebranch` represents the upstream of your current branch, that's pretty much the way `git rebase` already works.

Answer (score 0):

When you do rebase, git keeps old commits in his storage so they are not deleted, but history is changed. Learn [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

At first, take a look at [reflog](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_git_reflog). With this utility you can find necessary commits, which were rebased.

Then, simply use soft [reset](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) so that you point your `feature` branch to commit with old sha1 (the same like on the server).

And at last, to add changes of other commits, I would suggest use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#_rebase_cherry_pick).

Comment: Agreed this doesn't rewrite public history. It also doesn't really _rebase_ either though? That soft reset will end up with a (squashed) copy all the master changes in the index. I want an alias that will NOT rebase if it would requiring changing a public commit.